# Routing in Java web-application

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, url-routing

I created a web-application using Spring MVC/jsp. To navigate from one view to another I am using spring controller like the following -

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/transaction" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView defaultPage() {
    return new ModelAndView("transaction");
}



@RequestMapping(value = {"/getPartnerList"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
List<PartnerList> viewTransactionReport() {
    logger.info("inside getPartnerList");
    List<PartnerList> partnerList = CommonQuery.getPartnerList();
    logger.info("Partner List Size " + partnerList.size());
    return partnerList;
}
```

I first send the view request to the controller and after that I place the data-driven call to get JSON data.

Had I been using AngularJS, I could have used ng-route for navigation and sent only data-driven calls to the controller.

Is my approach correct in terms of efficiency and best practices? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are mixing server and client side technologies. Spring MVC creates pages at the server, so you would make a single request and return a ModelAndView object, holding the next view name and the data, that should appear on the site (partnerList).

Comment: @Stefan The request to /getPartnerList doesn't return a view. It's meant for an AJAX call to return some data after the "transaction" view loads.